# How to populate wheel with text, then make it spin (all in Flutter)?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, flutter-animation

I'm trying to make a spinning wheel, much like this:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_spinning_wheel#-readme-tab-

Except, I want to populate the wheel with names the user provides.  How can I overlay the text onto the wheel and get it to spin with the wheel?

The example listed above, uses an image that includes text, which obviously cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

For what i saw on API reference, the package lacks the feature to add names on each division. You have to edit the package, fork the package and make that feature or you need to request the dev of that made the package.

It's a image with the values on it. ([link](https://github.com/davidanaya/flutter-spinning-wheel/blob/master/example/assets/images/roulette-8-300.png))